# Get total hours with PHP & MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I have the following table

```
id | user_id | date                 | status
1  |    53   | 2018-09-18 06:59:54  | 1
2  |    62   | 2018-09-18 07:00:16  | 1
3  |    53   | 2018-09-18 09:34:12  | 2
4  |    53   | 2018-09-18 12:16:27  | 1
5  |    53   | 2018-09-18 18:03:19  | 2
6  |    62   | 2018-09-18 18:17:41  | 2
```

I would like to get the total working hours (from date range) and group them by user_id

UPDATE

The system does not "require" a check-out so if there is only one value can we set a default check out time lets say 19:00:00? IF not I can check every day at 21:00:00 if there is not a checkout time to manually insert it at 19:00:00

UPDATE 2

I have added a new field in the table "status" so the very first check-in of the date the status = 1 and every 2nd check-in the status = 2

So if a user check-ins for the 3rd time during the day the status will be 1 again etc.

I hope this will make things easier

Thanks

Comment: what you have tried?

Comment: Please update the sample data also showing status values.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of multiple check-in and check-out happening within a day, for a user:

- Utilizing [Correlated Subquery](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/correlated-subqueries.html), we can find corresponding "checkout_time" for every "checkin_time".
- Also, note the usage of [Ifnull()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull), [Timestamp()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestamp) functions etc, to consider default "checkout_time" as **19:00:00**, in case of no corresponding entry.
- Then, considering this enhanced data-set as [Derived Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html), we group the data-set based on the `user_id` and `date`. Date (**yyyy-mm-dd**) can be determined using [Date()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) function.
- Eventually, use [Timestampdiff()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) function with **Sum** aggregation, to determine the total work seconds for a `user_id` at a particular date.
- You can easily convert these total seconds to hours (either in your application code, or at the query itself (divide seconds by 3600).
- The reason I have preferred to compute using seconds, as **Timestampdiff()** function returns integer only. So there may be truncation errors, in case of multiple checkin/checkout(s).

Use the following query (replace `your_table` with your actual table name):

```
SELECT inner_nest.user_id, 
       DATE(inner_nest.checkin_time) AS work_date, 
       SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, 
                         inner_nest.checkin_time,
                         inner_nest.checkout_time)) AS total_work_seconds  
FROM 
(
  SELECT t1.user_id, 
         t1.date as checkin_time, 
         t1.status, 
         IFNULL( ( 
                  SELECT t2.date 
                  FROM your_table AS t2 
                  WHERE t2.user_id = t1.user_id 
                    AND t2.status = 2 
                    AND t2.date > t1.date 
                    AND DATE(t2.date) = DATE(t1.date) 
                  ORDER BY t2.date ASC LIMIT 1
                 ), 
                 TIMESTAMP(DATE(t1.date),'19:00:00')
               ) AS checkout_time 
  FROM `your_table` AS t1 
  WHERE t1.status = 1
) AS inner_nest 
GROUP BY inner_nest.user_id, DATE(inner_nest.checkin_time)
```

---

**Additional:** Following solution will work for the case when there is a single check-in, and corresponding check-out on the same date.

- You first need to group the dataset based on the `user_id` and `date`. Date (**yyyy-mm-dd**) can be determined using [Date()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) function.
- Now use aggregation functions like [Min()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_min) and [Max()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_max) to find the starting and closing time for a user_id at a particular date.
- Eventually, use [Timestampdiff()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) function to determine the working hours for a `user_id` at a particular date (difference between the closing and starting time)

Try the following query (replace `your_table` with your actual table name):

```
SELECT user_id, 
       DATE(`date`) AS working_date, 
       TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, MIN(`date`), MAX(`date`)) AS working_hours 
FROM your_table 
GROUP BY 
  user_id, 
  DATE(`date`)
```

Comment: I believe this one works if a user has one check-in & check-out per day. If there are multiple check-ins & check-outs during the date your query gets the first check-in and the last check-out and calculates the hours difference. We do have multiple check-ins & check-outs during the day and we need to calculate the total between each check-in & check-out

Comment: @Andr agreed. Please edit your question with this detail. It gets missed. I will work out a separate query.

Comment: @Andr also, does data ensure that for every checkin at a particular date, there is always a checkout on the same date ?

Comment: Please refrain from putting links to your own answer in the comments section. It's surely against SO etiquette.

Comment: @Strawberry thanks. Noted! Just wondering, if OP gets notifications, whenever a new answer is posted ?

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya Sorry for not mentioning it in my question. I apologise. The system does not "require" a check-out so if there is only one value can we set a default check out time lets say 19:00:00? IF not I can check every day at 21:00:00 if there is not a checkout time to manually insert it at 19:00:00

Comment: @madhurbhaiya Of course they do. And if they didn't, wouldn't it then be discourteous of you not to link to all of the other answers provided? Please remove ALL such comments.

Comment: @Strawberry how to find them all ?

Comment: @Andr can you please edit the question to all these details there. Other people may also refer to them, and try some solution!

Comment: Yep, it's going to take you a while

Comment: @Strawberry well I have removed whatever I could find.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya I have updated my original post. Looking forward to your new query. Thanks

Comment: @Andr check the updated answer. Note that I am returning working seconds instead of hours. Directly using TIMESTAMPDIFF to convert into hours will have truncation issues, as it returns an integer only. Instead, total seconds can be calculated and converted to hours accordingly

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya you are the best! great query!

Answer (score 0):

Use `TIMESTAMPDIFF` function

the query more like :

```
SELECT t1.user_id, TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,t1.date,t2.date) as difference
FROM your_table t1
       INNER JOIN your_table t2 on t1.user_id = t2.user_id
Group By t1.user_id
```

You can see this as preference [TimeStampDiff](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff)